# Error in converting nsstring to double value in ios

Tags: nsstring, double, nsdictionary

am getting the folloewing error while converting NSString in to double value.

```
        NSString *latValue = [retrieving valueForKey:@"lat"];
        double db = [latValue doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"db valiue is %f",db);
```

retrieving is my NSDictionary.
Error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e83860.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because that the "lat" is an NSArray, not an NSString?